# High chart (spark line) displaying "Created with High charts 4.0.1 No data to display" instead of display graph?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sparklines

High chart (spark line) displaying `Created with High charts 4.0.1 No data to display` instead of display graph?

```
title: {
    text: ''
},
credits: {
enabled: false
},
xAxis: {
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    categories: ['a','b','c']
},
yAxis: [{
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',


    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    labels:
    {
        enabled: false
    }
},
{
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',

    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    labels:
    {
        enabled: false
    }
}],
series: [{
    name: ' ',
    yAxis: 1,
    type: 'spline',
    data: [1,2,3],
    pointStart: 0
},
{
    name: ' ',
    yAxis: 1,
    type: 'spline',
    data: [4,5,6],
    pointStart: 0
}],
legend: {
    enabled: false,
    width: 100,
    floating: true,
    align: 'left',
    x: 0, // = marginLeft - default spacingLeft
    itemWidth: 60
},
chart: {
    height: 30,
    width: 100,
    marginBottom: 10
},
tooltip: {
    positioner: function () {
        return { x: -180, y: -25 };
    },
    shape: "square",
    backgroundColor: '#FCE9CE',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#F90',
    formatter: function () {
        var bpValue = [];
        var serviceDate;
        $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
            bpValue.push('<span>' + point.y + '</span>');
            serviceDate = point.x;
        });
        var content = "<span><b>Service:</b>" + serviceDate 
            + "</span><br /><span><b>BP Value :</b></span>";
        bpValue = bpValue.join('/');
        return content + bpValue;
    },
    shared: true
}
```

Sometimes It is not displaying any line or dot. instead of that simply showing alternate text that is `Created with Highcharts 4.0.1`. What would be the issue? how can resolve this?

Comment: Is the problem visible only when there is no data (as it should be) or when data is provided for a chart? Could you post a live example, like JSFiddle, of the problem? Your code is working fine - http://jsfiddle.net/bw0nyL12/

Comment: The data are dynamic. Basically it is a .Net application. Most of the time the problem occurs only when there is no data (or) no proper format of data. 
I have 10 links in a page. For each link click it will generate one graph. If the problem occurs in one graph, it is affecting rest of all charts.

Comment: Dynamic data: are you creating charts before data is loaded and then dynamically update series through setData? or are you waiting for data to load and then create a chart? If you could recreate the issue with at least 2 or 3 charts, then maybe the issue will be visible and we will be able to find the source of the problem? Please make sure that data has a proper format - otherwise that will be the issue and you will need to fix that first (parse data or use required format).

Comment: Yes the data has proper format. Yes we are waiting for data to load and then create a chart. Many times i am getting this issue in deployed URL(post deployment)

Comment: If you are waiting for data when creating a chart, then from the Highcharts point of view there is nothing dynamic here. It is possible to debug your code, but for that we need to replicate the issue - please provide code that is causing the issue, and since you have data in proper format, then you should be able to hard-code it into JSFiddle. If you will be having problems with creating a live example - feel free to ask.